# How can I pivot SQL query results by date and location for the last 3 report dates?

Tags: sql, pivot

I have table (UserReport), that lists users that are missing company required AD attributes.  In this table I have ReportDate column (which is the date of the weekly report I run).  I have a different locations field called Site rolls up to Division.  I want to give a historical pivot per site for that last 3 reportdates and the counts per site.  Below is what I am getting now.

SQL Query Ran

```
SELECT division, site, reportdate, COUNT(reportdate) as CountUsers 
FROM UserReport
WHERE division = 'US South'
GROUP BY division, site, reportdate
```

RESULTS

| Division | Site | ReportDate | CountUsers |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| US South | Texas | 2023-05-24 | 1 |
| US South | Florida | 2023-05-24 | 1 |
| US South | Ohio | 2023-05-24 | 1 |
| US South | Ohio | 2023-05-26 | 1 |
| US South | Kansas | 2023-05-19 | 5 |
| US South | Idaho | 2023-05-24 | 1 |
| US South | Utah | 2023-05-24 | 1 |
| US South | Georgia | 2023-05-24 | 1 |
| US South | Georgia | 2023-05-26 | 1 |

RESULTS that I want

| Division | Site | 2023-05-19 | 2023-05-24 | 2023-05-26 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| US South | Texas | 0 | 1 | 0 |
| US South | Florida | 0 | 1 | 0 |
| US South | Ohio | 0 | 1 | 1 |
| US South | Kansas | 5 | 0 | 0 |
| US South | Idaho | 0 | 1 | 0 |
| US South | Utah | 0 | 1 | 0 |
| US South | Georgia | 0 | 1 | 1 |

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're missing something into your pivot approach: splitting the date in the three dates you need. Once you split those values, you can apply conditional aggregation, and you'll get your output.

Using the `SUM` in place of the `COUNT` could avoid you issues, in case one column does not have any non-null value.

```
SELECT division, 
       site, 
       SUM(CASE WHEN reportdate = '2023-05-19' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS date1, 
       SUM(CASE WHEN reportdate = '2023-05-24' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS date2,
       SUM(CASE WHEN reportdate = '2023-05-26' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS date3
FROM UserReport
WHERE division = 'US South'
GROUP BY division, site
```

This should be good, given that you indicated you want only those last three dates.

Although if in future you would require to generalize on dates, then you would need a dynamic query, which is heavier in performance and has some issues tied to it. Doing such query also would require knowledge ofthe DBMS you're currently using, as each DBMS employs different syntax for dynamic querying.

Comment: I would like it to dynamically run on the last n number import dates in the table.  So, it would return that last 5 weeks.  I am assuming I would have to have some time of select statement to determine the last 5 dates, then loop it into sum() function.  I am currently running this on SQL Express 2022, but ultimately will be on 2019 DB Server.

Comment: Doing it would not require using dynamic querying, although it would require knowledge about the DBMS you're using and the version.